# Debugging 64-bit C++ from 64-bit .NET Code - how?

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, 64-bit

Visual studio tells me that 64-bit managed+unmanaged code debugging is not supported. Has anyone managed to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem too with the 64-bit debugger. Do you definitely need to debug both at the same time?

If not, when you need to debug native code you could run the managed application and the attach the debugger manually selecting "Native Code" as the debug type (as opposed to Automatic which might select both Managed and Native).

Comment: I'd prefer to debug both, but I'll try this 'Native Code' method, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+F5, once running,
Debug->Attach to Process. 
In the attach to: box select "Native code". 
Make sure in the processes box your vshost app is highlighted. 
Press "attach". 
Now your break-points in your native cpp code should trigger and the debugger will kick in.